# Moving UIButton when keyboard pops up

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, keyboard

I have below class. I am basically adding NSNotification to check whether keyboard is up. If keyboard is up, I change the frame of button to locate it on top of the keyboard. I think I did this in a correct manner, but the button apparently does not move. What could be the problem?

```
class vc: UIViewController {
var previousButton: UIButton!
var nextButton: UIButton!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: Selector("keyboardWillShow:"), name: UIKeyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: Selector("keyboardWillHide:"), name: UIKeyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)

  previousButton = UIButton(frame:  CGRectMake(margin + 20, containerView.frame.size.height + 10, 80, 30))
        previousButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "previous"), forState: .Normal)
        previousButton.addTarget(self, action: "previousButtonPressed2:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)

        nextButton = UIButton(frame:  CGRectMake(self.view.frame.width - margin - 80 - 20, containerView.frame.size.height + 10 , 80, 30))
        nextButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "next"), forState: .Normal)
        nextButton.addTarget(self, action: "nextButtonPressed2:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
        self.view.addSubview(previousButton)
        self.view.addSubview(nextButton)

}

   func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {
        if let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.CGRectValue() {
            previousButton = UIButton(frame:  CGRectMake(10 + 20,  self.view.frame.size.height - keyboardSize.height - 40, 80, 30))
        }
    }

    func keyboardWillHide(notification: NSNotification) {
        if let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.CGRectValue() {
              previousButton = UIButton(frame:  CGRectMake(10 + 20,  self.view.frame.size.height - 40, 80, 30))
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should check for `UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey` key in the `keyboardWillShow:` method instead of `UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey`. The same goes for `keyboardWillHide:` method:

```
func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {
    if let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.CGRectValue() {
        previousButton = UIButton(frame:  CGRectMake(10 + 20,  self.view.frame.size.height - keyboardSize.height - 40, 80, 30))
    }
}

func keyboardWillHide(notification: NSNotification) {
    if let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.CGRectValue() {
          previousButton = UIButton(frame:  CGRectMake(10 + 20,  self.view.frame.size.height - 40, 80, 30))
    }
}
```

`UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey` allows you to get the frame of the keyboard from before the keyboard animation starts when you really need a frame of the keyboard when keyboard is fully visible in the screen. This value can be retrieved using `UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey` key.

Comment: I tried this and there's no difference unfortunately.

Comment: Can you tell me how `height` (you are using `keyboardSize.height`) property is implemented in `CGRect` type? I assume that you added extension - Can you verify that it works correctly?

Comment: Height is correctly implemented in type of CGRect.  It is just calculated from the variable keyboardSize in my code.